# Unfolding a 3d object into a 2d plane

Tags: geometry

I got the following 3d model of an exhaust pipe:

[image: Top view]
[image: Side view]

The model consists of multiple cylinders and flat cones.
I want to print out the cutting shape of those and therefore need to "unfold" the cylinder/cone into a flat plane. There are programs, that can do that but they are not free (the difficulty is, that the top/bottom of some cones is at an angle, wich seems to be more complicated)...

Is there a way to do this in blender?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is a built-in addon called [Export Paper model](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/paper_model.html) which allows you to unfold your mesh so you can later on print it and reconstruct the shape with paper based on the pattern

You can manage the way the model unfolds in edit mode with seams and by using the unfold button on the side pannel

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had to do some trickery to get everything right because exporting everything at once generates to many numbers. I couldn't even see the whole shape. But exporting every part separately, everything worked out perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that you can print out in 2D and assemble into the final shape, your 2D version needs to have zero distortion.  The tradeoff for distortion is seams: to do that, you need to cut the surface.  Frequently, our intuitions about how things need to be cut are off.

This cylinder can be mapped onto a flat surface with only a single seam:

[image]

But this cylinder cannot:

[image]

We can see that our angles have changed; less obvious is that our lengths have changed as well.  In order to create a 2D map of this shape that is free of distortion, we need to use many more seams:

[image]

Once seamed, we can use Blender's unwrapping to create a distortion-free 2D mapping, provided that we mark enough seams to allow it to do so.  Once we unwrap, we no longer need any addons to turn the 3D shape into a 2D shape.
We can use geometry nodes:

[image]

I send the UV map as a vector input to the modifier, then I rip the mesh's edges to allow seaming; then I set the positions to the unwrapped positions; then I scale by the ratio of the square root of the area of the first face to get the same world size as my mesh (since there is no distortion, this proportion is the same for all faces); then, to eliminate unnecessary seams,  I merge by distance.